# Google Web Calendar and Chrome Extensions

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-calendar-api

I have a Chrome extension that was working in the old design of the Google Calendar website, dynamically injecting information on the calendar that my users want to see.

With the new design, direct modifications to the DOM are reversed in short order.

Is there a new way, or an API of some sort, to interact with the DOM of the calendar webpage to add more information?

Or is there a way to get a new "calendar system" embedded into the calendar page?

Here's a sample of some of what the extension does, adding labels in each day cell:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried visiting the documentation by [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/overview)?

Comment: @MαπμQμαπkγVπ.0 I'd not been aware of the "Calendar Gadgets" and they look promising... but there is a notice on that page: "Warning: Calendar gadgets are now deprecated and will cease to be supported after January 31, 2018"